# Why I cannot free those big memory block

Tags: c, unix, memory, memory-management

Recently, I encountered a strange error while debugging a program. We allocate a big buffer. After freeing it, the memory did not go back to the OS. And then the following allocation could fail due to lack of memory. I then made the following test program. I allocated memory for pointer `c` and did not `free` it to simulate my real program. (In my program, there is a small memory leak caused by OpenMPI calls.)

It will fail at the 18th line on a computer (Mac) with 3 GB free memory due to insufficient memory. I know pointer `c` would cause memory fragmentation. But for these big memory buffers like `a` and `b`, they are allocated by `mmap`, not `brk`. They should be able to be freed directly, right? What should I do to solve this problem?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    float *a=malloc(1250000000);
    memset(a, (char)1, 1250000000);

    float *b=malloc(1250000000);
    memset(b, (char)1, 1250000000);

    float *c=malloc(10);
    memset(c, (char)1, 10);

    free(b);
    free(a);

    float *d=malloc(2000000000);  /* FAILS HERE */
    memset(d, (char)1, 2000000000);
}
```

Comment: It could be the case of memory fragmentation due to the `xalloc` algorithm.

Comment: Either don't make such big allocations or switch to a 64-bit target.

Comment: Is this Linux, or some other Unix variant? Which one, and what version?

Comment: The actual problem happened on a 64GB debian 6 linux server. I did not remember the exact version number. I had done similar test on that machine with larger buffer (30Gbyte) too. Result is the same. This program is tested on my own mac.

Comment: Hi David, what do you mean by switch to 64-bit target?

Comment: [`A 32-bit register can store 2**32 different values...Hence, a processor with 32-bit memory addresses can directly access 4 GiB of byte-addressable memory.`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit) . I think this is why David advised to switch to a 64-bit target, with more than 4Gb of RAM, to solve the problem you wrote in your question.

Comment: But all my test machines are 64-bit

Comment: A possible alternative to going to a 64 bit target is to use a different memory allocator, like `dlmalloc` (http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html).

Comment: "Fails here" How do you know? There's no error checking. Also, what does "fails" mean, that is what happens?

Comment: Always check failure of `calloc`, `malloc` etc... And probably disable memory overcommit

Comment: 1) Why do you call `calloc` if you do `memset` just after? If you need zeros, don't `memset` to 1, OTOH if you need ones, use `malloc` instead of `calloc`. Don't initialize twice. 2) You do `memset` on the `a` block twice but do not on `b` — is it intentional? 3) Do you really need `memset` at all? Doesn't the allocation problem arise without writing to the allocated blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention in comments you are observing the behavior of your program under your Mac. Assuming you mean OS X, then your program is not behaving the way you believe it to be. The allocator does `mmap` calls for each `calloc` call, and the `free` call does not result in `munmap`, because the allocator is anticipating reusing the memory you allocated.

This can be verified by using `dtruss`:

```
$ dtruss -f -t mmap ./a.out 
    PID/THRD  SYSCALL(args)          = return
57843/0x16bf38:  mmap(0x10C119000, 0x2000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x1000)       = 0x10C119000 0
57843/0x16bf38:  mmap(0x10C11B000, 0x1000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x3000)       = 0x10C11B000 0
57843/0x16bf38:  mmap(0x10C11C000, 0x1FC0, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x4000)       = 0x10C11C000 0

$
```

Notice the three calls to `mmap`. However, there are no calls to `brk` or `sbrk`, nor to `munmap`:

```
$ dtruss -f -t brk ./a.out 
    PID/THRD  SYSCALL(args)          = return

$ dtruss -f -t sbrk ./a.out 
    PID/THRD  SYSCALL(args)          = return

$ dtruss -f -t munmap ./a.out 
    PID/THRD  SYSCALL(args)          = return

$
```

Comment: This optimization strategy may work but why there's no free when a new, distinct block of memory is required?

Comment: Oh, your program executes to completion on my system because my Mac has 16 GB. If your Mac has sufficient swap, your program should complete (albeit, slowly).

Comment: @black: Hmmm... the allocator wasn't that smart?

Comment: but I observed exact same behavior in our linux server. Do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: Pre-allocate the large memory you need up front, and don't let go of them.

Comment: Hi jxh, that is difficult for us. Because this is a large program and this problem appears when we were solving some specific problems. We cannot afford to change the whole structure.

Comment: If it is too expensive to change the software, buy more RAM. But a custom allocator that behaves the way I described in my previous comment is probably the best solution.

Comment: I just call munmap to those big buffers, but seems not working either.

Comment: If you have fragmentation, your process may require more memory than what you requested. If the request requires the process to grow beyond what available resources allow, the allocation will fail. The best way to avoid that failure is to grab the memory you need upfront, and reuse it, rather than freeing it and trying to reallocate it later.